# Parameter n_iter in scikit-learn's SGDClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, stochastic-gradient-descent

I have a doubt concerning parameter `n_iter` in function `SGDClassifier` from scikit-learn. Hereafter is the definition:

> **n_iter** : int, optional
>
> The number of passes over the training data (aka epochs). The number of iterations is set to 1 using partial_fit. Defaults to 5.

For a data set of size $n$, I can think of two interpretations for the text above:

- *Interpretation 1*: The algorithm only picks randomly `n_iter` data points in total and computes the gradient at those points, so that the total number of evaluations of the gradient is `n_iter` (**so only 5 by default ?!**).
- *Interpretation 2*: The algorithm goes through the whole data set `n_iter` times, picking for each of the `n_iter` loops the $n$ points (random sampling without replacement basically) so that the total number of evaluations of the gradient is $n \ \times $`n_iter`.

Given that the advice of scikit-learn is to pick `n_iter` equal to `np.ceil(10**6/n)`, I have trouble understanding how for $n=1,000,000$ the algorithm is expected to converge after just 1 computation if interpretation 1 above is correct...

> Empirically, we found that SGD converges after observing approx. 10^6 training samples. Thus, a reasonable first guess for the number of iterations is `n_iter = np.ceil(10**6 / n)`, where `n` is the size of the training set.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Description of the function is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html) and technical documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be the second.

I always answer these questions by looking at the source code (which in sklearn is of very high quality, and is written extremely clearly).  The function in question is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/89247fcd7f02bbd92c9da141250ec8b82caf8dd0/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L529) (I searched for `SGDClassifier` then followed the function calls until I got to this one, which is a low level routine).

Breaking out the important piece:

```
for epoch in range(n_iter):
    ...
    for i in range(n_samples):
        ...
```

That's exactly the pattern you would expect for `n_iter` passes over the full training data.